# SQL Query takes long time to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am fetching some data from one table. But it is taking minimum 10 sec to execute.

Table contains records in lacks.

below is my ruby query.

@royalty_artist = RoyaltyReport.find(:all,:select =>'local_revenue, upc',              :conditions => ["name = ? && upc in (?) && file_id in (?)",name,upc,file_id])

Also all three columns has indexing.

Please suggest me how should i decrease execution time?

Comment: How does the generated SQL look like? You are using SQLite, do you?

Comment: Generated sql look like this:                                 SELECT  local_revenue, upc 

FROM `royalty_reports` 

WHERE (name = ' Manuel Urias y su Conjunto Madera' 

&& upc in ('610447546223'...............) &&

file_id in (2925,2926,3091,3175,3176,3177,.............));